# Find the number of positive integral solutions of the equation $\frac{1}{x} + \frac{2}{y} = \frac{1}{4}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the number of positive integral solutions of the equation
$$\frac{1}{x} + \frac{2}{y} = \frac{1}{4}$$

**My attempt:**

$$\begin{align}
y+2x&=\frac{xy}{4} \\
4y+8x &= xy \\
8x &= y(x-4) \\
\end{align}$$

How can i proceed?

Comment: Use [SFFT](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Simon%27s_Favorite_Factoring_Trick) to factor $xy-8x-4y = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

From $4y+8x=xy$ we have $xy-4y-8x=0\implies(x-4)(y-8)=32$. Note that $-32=1\cdot32, -\cdot16, \dots,-1\cdot-32,-2\cdot-16\dots$ Use this to solve for $x$ and $y$. You will find that there are $12$ solutions in total.

Comment: You should have $-8x$, which means your equations are slightly off from then on

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242)

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying by $4xy$ gives $0 = xy - 8x - 4y = (x - 4)(y - 8) - 32$ so that

$$(x - 4)(y - 8) = 32 = 2^{5}.$$

There are $12$ solutions to this equation because there are $12$ solutions to the equation $a + b = 5$ (each of the two factors in the product $2^{5}$ must contribute some number of $2's$, and it must sum to $5$).

Comment: I’d say there are $6$ (nonnegative integer) solutions to $a+b=5$, and then the number of solutions $x,y$ is twice that.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242)